# Youtube API get channels a user is a subtitle editor for

Tags: youtube-api

Is is possible to query the YouTube api for channels that a user is a Subtitle Editor for? I can't seem to get this work using the Channel list endpoint.

I'm looking at the `channels` endpoint described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

It appears that there are at least 4 ways to use this endpoint:

- List by channel id
- List by YouTube username
- List my channel
- List channels managed by a content owner.

I was hoping that channels that a user is the Subtitle Editor for would be returned in the the `ListByYouTubeUsername` query but this doesn't seem to be the case. It it possible to get this data using the API?

Comment: Can you elaborate about what is: `Subtitle Editor`, please?

Comment: It doesn't seem even possible from the YouTube UI for a given video to get which channels were subtitle editors for a given video, correct? Here is an example of video which seems to call on the service of a subtitle editor: [`o8NPllzkFhE`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8NPllzkFhE)

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes The subtitle editor role is described in this link https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11983512#zippy=%2Cget-access-to-subtitle-editor-role-as-non-channel-ownermanager%2Cgive-access-to-subtitle-editor-role-as-a-channel-owner-or-manager